# How to convert between keyboard scan code and USB keyboard usage index?

Tags: windows, keyboard, scancodes

I'm working with a Windows virtual keyboard driver to generate keystrokes, and it requires specifying keys using the USB keyboard usage index. (See ["Windows Platform Design Notes - Keyboard Scan Code Specification"](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc) appendix C for a list of usage indices and corresponding keys.) However, the keys I need to type will be specified by virtual key code.

Windows provides functions for converting between virtual key codes and scan codes, but I haven't found any way of converting between scan codes and these usage indices. Other than writing my own function that converts the hundred-and-change possible scan codes that my virtual keyboard driver may need to type, does Microsoft provide a function for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hash table will convert from scan code to USB usage ID. Note that it only includes page IDs with a corresponding usage page of 7.

The translations were acquired from the Microsoft document [USB HID to PS/2 Scan Code Translation Table](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf) and from [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5J41WCQP) that conveniently already has all that information formatted into a Python data structure.

```
std::unordered_map<WORD, BYTE> scanCodeToUSBUsageIndex({
    {0x00FF, 0x01}, // Overrun Error
    {0x00FC, 0x02}, // POST Fail
    {0x001E, 0x04}, // a A
    {0x0030, 0x05}, // b B
    {0x002E, 0x06}, // c C
    {0x0020, 0x07}, // d D
    {0x0012, 0x08}, // e E
    {0x0021, 0x09}, // f F
    {0x0022, 0x0A}, // g G
    {0x0023, 0x0B}, // h H
    {0x0017, 0x0C}, // i I
    {0x0024, 0x0D}, // j J
    {0x0025, 0x0E}, // k K
    {0x0026, 0x0F}, // l L
    {0x0032, 0x10}, // m M
    {0x0031, 0x11}, // n N
    {0x0018, 0x12}, // o O
    {0x0019, 0x13}, // p P
    {0x0010, 0x14}, // q Q
    {0x0013, 0x15}, // r R
    {0x001F, 0x16}, // s S
    {0x0014, 0x17}, // t T
    {0x0016, 0x18}, // u U
    {0x002F, 0x19}, // v V
    {0x0011, 0x1A}, // w W
    {0x002D, 0x1B}, // x X
    {0x0015, 0x1C}, // y Y
    {0x002C, 0x1D}, // z Z
    {0x0002, 0x1E}, // 1 !
    {0x0003, 0x1F}, // 2 @
    {0x0004, 0x20}, // 3 #
    {0x0005, 0x21}, // 4 $
    {0x0006, 0x22}, // 5 %
    {0x0007, 0x23}, // 6 ^
    {0x0008, 0x24}, // 7 &
    {0x0009, 0x25}, // 8 *
    {0x000A, 0x26}, // 9 (
    {0x000B, 0x27}, // 0 )
    {0x001C, 0x28}, // Return
    {0x0001, 0x29}, // Escape
    {0x000E, 0x2A}, // Backspace
    {0x000F, 0x2B}, // Tab
    {0x0039, 0x2C}, // Space
    {0x000C, 0x2D}, // - _
    {0x000D, 0x2E}, // = +
    {0x001A, 0x2F}, // [ {
    {0x001B, 0x30}, // ] }
    {0x002B, 0x31}, // \ |
    {0x002B, 0x32}, // Europe 1 (Note 2)
    {0x0027, 0x33}, // ; :
    {0x0028, 0x34}, // ' "
    {0x0029, 0x35}, // ` ~
    {0x0033, 0x36}, // , <
    {0x0034, 0x37}, // . >
    {0x0035, 0x38}, // / ?
    {0x003A, 0x39}, // Caps Lock
    {0x003B, 0x3A}, // F1
    {0x003C, 0x3B}, // F2
    {0x003D, 0x3C}, // F3
    {0x003E, 0x3D}, // F4
    {0x003F, 0x3E}, // F5
    {0x0040, 0x3F}, // F6
    {0x0041, 0x40}, // F7
    {0x0042, 0x41}, // F8
    {0x0043, 0x42}, // F9
    {0x0044, 0x43}, // F10
    {0x0057, 0x44}, // F11
    {0x0058, 0x45}, // F12
    {0xE037, 0x46}, // Print Screen (Note 1)
    {0x0046, 0x47}, // Scroll Lock
    {0xE052, 0x49}, // Insert (Note 1)
    {0xE047, 0x4A}, // Home (Note 1)
    {0xE049, 0x4B}, // Page Up (Note 1)
    {0xE053, 0x4C}, // Delete (Note 1)
    {0xE04F, 0x4D}, // End (Note 1)
    {0xE051, 0x4E}, // Page Down (Note 1)
    {0xE04D, 0x4F}, // Right Arrow (Note 1)
    {0xE04B, 0x50}, // Left Arrow (Note 1)
    {0xE050, 0x51}, // Down Arrow (Note 1)
    {0xE048, 0x52}, // Up Arrow (Note 1)
    {0x0045, 0x53}, // Num Lock
    {0xE035, 0x54}, // Keypad / (Note 1)
    {0x0037, 0x55}, // Keypad *
    {0x004A, 0x56}, // Keypad -
    {0x004E, 0x57}, // Keypad +
    {0xE01C, 0x58}, // Keypad Enter
    {0x004F, 0x59}, // Keypad 1 End
    {0x0050, 0x5A}, // Keypad 2 Down
    {0x0051, 0x5B}, // Keypad 3 PageDn
    {0x004B, 0x5C}, // Keypad 4 Left
    {0x004C, 0x5D}, // Keypad 5
    {0x004D, 0x5E}, // Keypad 6 Right
    {0x0047, 0x5F}, // Keypad 7 Home
    {0x0048, 0x60}, // Keypad 8 Up
    {0x0049, 0x61}, // Keypad 9 PageUp
    {0x0052, 0x62}, // Keypad 0 Insert
    {0x0053, 0x63}, // Keypad . Delete
    {0x0056, 0x64}, // Europe 2 (Note 2)
    {0xE05D, 0x65}, // App
    {0x0059, 0x67}, // Keypad =
    {0x005D, 0x68}, // F13
    {0x005E, 0x69}, // F14
    {0x005F, 0x6A}, // F15
    {0x007E, 0x85}, // Keypad , (Brazilian Keypad .)
    {0x0073, 0x87}, // Keyboard Int'l 1 ろ (Ro)
    {0x0070, 0x88}, // Keyboard Int'l 2 かたかな ひらがな ローマ字 (Katakana/Hiragana)
    {0x007D, 0x89}, // Keyboard Int'l 3 ￥ (Yen)
    {0x0079, 0x8A}, // Keyboard Int'l 4 前候補 変換 (次候補) 全候補 (Henkan)
    {0x007B, 0x8B}, // Keyboard Int'l 5 無変換 (Muhenkan)
    {0x005C, 0x8C}, // Keyboard Int'l 6 (PC9800 Keypad , )
    {0x00F2, 0x90}, // Keyboard Lang 1 한/영 (Hanguel/English)
    {0x00F1, 0x91}, // Keyboard Lang 2 한자 (Hanja)
    {0x0078, 0x92}, // Keyboard Lang 3 かたかな (Katakana)
    {0x0077, 0x93}, // Keyboard Lang 4 ひらがな (Hiragana)
    {0x0076, 0x94}, // Keyboard Lang 5 半角/全角 (Zenkaku/Hankaku)
    {0x001D, 0xE0}, // Left Control
    {0x002A, 0xE1}, // Left Shift
    {0x0038, 0xE2}, // Left Alt
    {0xE05B, 0xE3}, // Left GUI
    {0xE01D, 0xE4}, // Right Control
    {0x0036, 0xE5}, // Right Shift
    {0xE038, 0xE6}, // Right Alt
    {0xE05C, 0xE7}  // Right GUI
});
```

Comment: Thanks for not being DenverCoder9 and posted the answer when you found it, it really helped me and it will now be part of the new Ubuntu installer to do keyboard layout detection. :)

Comment: @spydon Haha, good reference. Happy to help!